# Why wiil not my program insert to the database?

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, pandas

I have made a program that behaves strangs since it works on simple excel sheets.

I can briefly describe my problem:

1. The head which is also Hour disappers and I have tried both header = None and parscols = ["", ""], still the header will not join the database
2. The values ​​of the excel sheet will not enter the database, even though I have avoided the missing data.

This is my code:

```
from src.server.connectToDB import get_sql_conn
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cursor = get_sql_conn().cursor()
    local_files = 'C:\\Users\\dersimw\\Source\Repos\\nordpoolAnalyse\\data\\2011-3.xlsx'
    excelFile = pd.ExcelFile(local_files)

    ark = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
         "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"]

    for sheets in ark:
        df = excelFile.parse(sheets).head(5)
        print(df.dropna(axis=1, how='all'))
        for key, rows in df.items():
            print("# Kolonne: ", "\n")
            columnInsertSql = "INSERT INTO DataSets (Hour, BlockBuyNet, BlockSell, RejectedBlockBuy, RejectedBlockSell, NetImports) VALUES"
            rowCounter = 0

            for column in rows.items():
                columnInsertSql += str(column)

                if rowCounter != len(list(rows.items())):
                    columnInsertSql += ", "
                rowCounter += 1

            print("## SQL: " + columnInsertSql)

            cursor.execute(columnInsertSql)
            cursor.commit()
```

This is the result when I print `df.dropna (axis = 1, how = 'all')`:

> Hour       0       1   ...        21      22      23
>
> 0     Accepted Block Buy     112     112   ...       227      52      52
>
> 1     Accepted Block Sell  1573.2  1575.2   ...    1833.8  1728.3  1649.3
>
> 2     Rejected Block Buy     NaN     NaN   ...       NaN     NaN     NaN
>
> 3     Rejected Block Sell     NaN     NaN   ...       NaN     NaN     NaN
>
> 4          Net Imports  2652.3  2505.9   ...      2932    2962    2897

Comment: What does`print("## SQL: " + columnInsertSql)` print?

Comment: This line will print this out:INSERT INTO DataSets (Hour, BlockBuyNet, BlockSell, RejectedBlockBuy, RejectedBlockSell, NetImports) VALUES(0, 'Accepted Block Buy'), (1, 'Accepted Block Sell'), (2, 'Rejected Block Buy'), (3, 'Rejected Block Sell'), (4, 'Net Imports'),

Comment: Your INSERT names 5 columns but your VALUES clauses only specify 2 values.

Comment: ok thanks, do you have any ideas how i can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to drop NAs but you forgot to put the "inplace" flag, this why when the dataframe is printed out it appears that you don't have any row with missing values but the original Df remains unchanged.

```
 for sheets in ark:
    df = excelFile.parse(sheets).head(5)
    df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
```

Alternatively you can re-declare DF like this:

```
 for sheets in ark:
    df = excelFile.parse(sheets).head(5)
    df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Also, I would recommend using Pandas to_sql functionality to make your life much easier. 
You can upload the entire DF instead of a row at a time like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase')

#Fill in your code to loop through workbooks here

for sheets in ark:
    df = excelFile.parse(sheets).head(5)
    df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
    df.columns =['Hour','BlockBuyNet','BlockSell','RejectedBlockBuy','RejectedBlockSell','NetImports']
    df.to_sql('DataSets', con = engine, if_exists='append', index = False)
```

Comment: Thank you Anton! I have never used create_engine and I am a beginner. Should scott:tiger by replaced by my own name ? and where in this code can I take in the excel sheet ?

Comment: @Dersimwaisi yes, you are going to have to change your sql connection requirements per your SQL engine, username, password, etc. You can find more info here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

Re loop through excel sheets; you can use the code that you already written up. Don't see why it would not work.

Comment: Thank you, Anton Petrosyuk. I prefer to use read_excel.. but the parse will not work when rather use read_excel then ExcelFile..I dont know why parse dont work when i switch from read_excel to Excelfile